# What does RESTful web service actually does that HTTP programming doesn't? What is the main use of RESTful WS

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-architecture

I know RESTful WS is an architecture all together, which is a new way of implementing Web Services over old fashioned JAX-RPC's.

In RESTful, we use @GET, @POST, etc to manage calls/develop resources. Same can be achieved using HTTP programming (both are stateless too). 
But what are other core main uses or need for bringing/implementing RESTful? As everything we do in it, can be done using HTTP programming (in which we use same methods)?

Comment: this kinda sounds like why use json when we have xml... Correct?

Comment: No. In REST, implementation is done using @GET and then we write our java method. So whatever it is doing can be done using HTTP programming too. So there is some other reason why REST introduced. I am trying to dig that. Sorry if am not making my doubt clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is comparing different things. HTTP is a protocol, while REST is an architectural style. This is like asking what a house does that a brick doesn't. It doesn't make sense. HTTP can be a building block of a REST application.

REST is not about HTTP or any particular protocol. REST is about applying the successful design decisions of the Web itself to software development. The problem is terminology. 99.9% of the so called REST applications around the internet aren't really RESTful, because REST became a buzzword to refer to any HTTP API that isn't SOAP. Some REST advocates gave up on fighting for the proper usage of the term and now refer to REST applications as Hypermedia.

Like the Web, REST is intended for software development in the scale of decades. REST makes it easier to evolve your application without breaking clients. Think about how today you can still access websites that were created decades ago, and almost everything still works fine. If you're creating software that has long-term objectives in the scale of several years, then maybe REST is adequate for you. If that's not what you really need, then getting REST right is not important. Just use whatever works for you, and at this point I think nobody cares anymore if you call it REST.

Comment: So its more of specific principles or guidelines to build an application. REST just uses or specifies how to do it and nothing more than that?

Comment: REST is an architectural *style*, intended to lead to applications that behave and scale like the Web itself. It doesn't specify how to do something, but rather what you shouldn't do.

Comment: I was asked this specific question of what did REST bring when all this existed. Was confused on that

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a transfer protocol.

RESTful is a group of principles.

Basically a RESTful web service is a particular HTTP application that follow the following principles:

- client server
- stateless
- cacheable
- layered

Comment: Can't all this be achieved using HTTP programming? It can be also be made client server. We can use same HTTP methods, can be made stateless.

Comment: Yes, RESTful is a subset of HTTP applications. If you respects the principles and standards of RESTful your HTTP application is also a RESTful web service.

Comment: Ok. So is there any other main reason for introduction / use of RESTful?

Comment: Not to nitpick words...but HTTP is actually an application protocol. The second T stands for "transfer" and not "transport." HTTP is an implementation of an application protocol that follows the constraints of the REST architecture style.

Comment: Anuj, the requirement for a high degree of decoupling comes to mind. Like the World Wide Web, for instance.

Comment: You are true Jonathan... was a typo... I edit the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The question is not "REST versus HTTP-Programing". REST is a higher concept on how to to create distributed web applications. HTTP is a concrete technology . REST defines some constraints which are considered as good practice.

HTTP is just a technology which is well suited to implement REST-Style services:

- Addressability   => in HTTP every resource can be addressed through a unique identifier (URI)
- multiple Representations  => every resource can have multiple representations (JSON, XML) - a HTTP-Request for instance can 'ask' for the right representation (via headers)
- Common Interface => Instead of creating an application specific interface (Methodnames in SOAP) HTTP already provides an Interface: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE ...)
- Stateless        => HTTP-Requests are stateless by design
- Hypermedia       => The application state (client) is driven by examining the links contained in the representations